# Integrating holomorphic function with respect to one component yields holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

The following statement and proof is taken from $\textit{Complex Geometry}$ (Huybrechts).

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}^{n}$ be an open subset and let $V \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open neighbourhood of the boundary of $B_{\varepsilon}(0)\subset \mathbb{C}$. Assume that $f\colon V\times U \to \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic function. Then
>   $$
> g(z):=g(z_1,\ldots, z_n):= \int_{\vert \xi \vert = \varepsilon} f(\xi, z_1,\ldots,z_n) d\xi
> $$
>   is a holomorphic function on $U$.
>
> $\textit{Proof}.$ Let $z\in U$. If $\vert \xi \vert = \varepsilon$ then there exists a polydisc $B_{\delta(\xi)}(\xi) \times B_{\delta'(\xi)}(z) \subset V\times U$ on which $f$ has a power series expansion.
>   Since $\partial{B_{\varepsilon}}(0)$ is compact we can find a finite number of points $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_k\in \partial{B_{\varepsilon}(0)}$ and positive real numbers $\delta(\xi_1),\ldots, \delta(\xi_k)$ such that 
>   $$
> \bigcup \partial{B_{\varepsilon}}(0) \cap B_{\delta(\xi_i)/2}(\xi_i) \text{ is a disjoint union}
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> \partial{B_{\varepsilon}(0)} = \bigcup \partial{B_{\varepsilon}(0)} \cap \overline{B_{\delta(\xi_i)/2}(\xi_i)}. 
> $$
>   Hence, $g(z)=\int_{\vert \xi \vert = \varepsilon}f(\xi,z_1,\ldots,z_n)d\xi = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \int_{\vert \xi \vert = \varepsilon, \vert \xi_i-\xi \vert < \delta(\xi_i)/2} f d\xi$.

It clear to me that the balls $B_{\delta(\xi)}(\xi)$ cover the boundary of $B_{\varepsilon}(0)$, and so finitely many suffice to cover it. However, I do not see how we can choose them such that the two written properties hold.
Moreover, assuming we found a finite number of points having those two properties, I am wondering why we have 
$$
\int_{\vert \xi \vert = \varepsilon}f(\xi,z_1,\ldots,z_n)d\xi = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \int_{\vert \xi \vert = \varepsilon, \vert \xi_i-\xi \vert < \delta(\xi_i)/2} f d\xi$
$$
Set $D:=\bigcup \partial{B_{\varepsilon}}(0) \cap B_{\delta(\xi_i)/2}(\xi_i)$ and let $\overline{D}$ denote the closure of $D$ in $\partial{B_{\varepsilon}(0)}$, then we have $\overline{D}= \partial{B_{\varepsilon}(0)}$ by assumption. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \int_{\vert \xi \vert = \varepsilon, \vert \xi_i-\xi \vert < \delta(\xi_i)/2} f d\xi = \int_{D}fd\xi$ because the union is disjoint. How is this equal to the $\int_{\overline{D}}f d\xi$?